# Insert same row values except some columns

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table like this but not just 5 columns(maybe greater than 10)

```
ID  |   FileName    |   Type    |   Other1  |   Other 2 
1       image1.eps      3           assff       12321
2       image2.eps      3           asdfs       12321
3       image3.eps      3           asdaf       24124
```

And a query like this:

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @FileName = 'image1.eps'

INSERT INTO DigitalAssets
VALUES(
    (SELECT max(ID)+1 FROM DigitalAssets)
    ,(SUBSTRING(@FileName,0,LEN(@FileName)-4)+'.jpg')
    ,(1)
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 Other1 FROM DigitalAssets WHERE FileName = @FileName )
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 Other2 FROM DigitalAssets WHERE FileName = @FileName )
)
```

Now I want to create a stored procedure that will insert the same values except `id, filename, and type` . I can do it like this but there are too many columns(or am I just lazy). What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You do know there's something like IDENTITY for inserting IDs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting your ID has been set its identity to true. This code might work for you.

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @FileName = 'image1.eps'

INSERT INTO DigitalAssets([FileName], Type, Other1, Other2) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@FileName,0,LEN(@FileName)-4)+'.jpg',1, Other1, Other2 
FROM DigitalAssets WHERE FileName = @FileName
```

In case it is not, you could try this.

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @FileName = 'image1.eps'

INSERT INTO DigitalAssets(id, [FileName], Type, Other1, Other2) 
SELECT (SELECT id
FROM DigitalAssets o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DigitalAssets o2 WHERE o2.id > o1.id)) 
SUBSTRING(@FileName,0,LEN(@FileName)-4)+'.jpg',1, Other1, Other2 
FROM DigitalAssets WHERE FileName = @FileName
```